# Como hacer que una imagen ocupe todo el alto del contenedor en jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Estoy tratando de hacer que una imagen ocupe todo el alto del contenedor, pero no lo hace, dependiendo de la imagen que se le este pasando, esta ocupa la mitad o casi la totalidad del alto incluso si la imagen es de gran resolución, alguien podría darme una mano con esto? Estoy trabajando en jetpack compose.
He tratado con los contentScale y aun asi no lo he logrado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo es el siguiente

```
Card(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(10.dp),
    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
        containerColor = card
    )
) {
    Row {
        SubcomposeAsyncImage(
            model = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg",
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxHeight()
        ){
            val state = painter.state
            if(state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading || state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error){
                CircularProgressIndicator()
            }else{
                SubcomposeAsyncImageContent()
            }
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
            Text(
                text = "Title NAME",
                color = textColor,
                fontSize = 20.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )
            Row {
                Point()
                Text(text = "Alive - Human", color = textColor, fontSize = 16.sp)
            }
            Text(
                text = "Last known location:",
                color = textSubTitle,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
            Text(text = "Earth (Replacement Dimension)", color = textColor)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Text(
                text = "First seen in:",
                color = textSubTitle,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                fontSize = 12.sp
            )
            Text(text = "Rick Sanchez", color = textColor)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Recuerda que `fillMaxSize` habilita al componente a ocupar todo el espacio disponible, pero el componente puede decidir solo ocupar una parte.

Comment: Has probado a darle a ese Row principal, todo el tamaño disponible del Card. Y también habría que ver el content scale de esa imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Noto que usas `Modifier.fillMaxHeight()`, pero también deberías usar el modificador `Modifier.fillMaxSize()`, que de acuerdo a la documentación, provoca que un elemento ocupe todo el espacio disponible.

Revisa:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers?hl=es-419

```
 ...
 ...
 Row {
    SubcomposeAsyncImage(
        model = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/avatar/1.jpeg",
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .fillMaxSize() //* Agregar!
    ) {
        val state = painter.state
        if (state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Loading || state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
        } else {
            SubcomposeAsyncImageContent()
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
```